# MySQLd.exe is continuously crashing

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, innodb, wampserver

I have a WAMP server setup, MySQL is crashing continuously, I did not found any error into the error log it's printing **[Note] MySQL normally shutdown.**

When I checked the Windows logs I found the following error,
In Application:

Event 1000,Application Error

1. Faulting application name:mysqld.exe,version:5.6.12.0 timestamp:0x519ba665
2. Faulting module name:mysqld.exe,version:5.6.12.0 timestamp:0x519ba665
3. Exception Code:0xc0000005
4. Faulting offset:0x001f6867
5. Faulting process id:0x9b4
6. Faulting Application path:c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqld.exe
7. Faulting Module path:c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqld.exe

And in the System log:
 **Event Id :7034**
**The wampmysqld terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 12 time(s)**

Why MySQL is keeps crashing and how we fix this? Kindly suggest.

```
**Please Find Error log of my server**
2016-09-13 15:48:49 8740 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown

2016-09-13 15:48:49 8740 [Note] Giving 1 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2016-09-13 15:48:49 8740 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2016-09-13 15:48:49 8740 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 1 remaining clients
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Warning] wampmysqld: Forcing close of thread 1  user: 'root'

2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Binlog end
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-09-13 15:48:51 8740 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 17597920029
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-09-13 15:48:53 8740 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: what's in MySQL error log?

Comment: Show use the mysql error log

Comment: Hii, I am getting below error in MySQL error log    "2016-09-17 17:50:40 8992 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2016-09-17 17:50:40 8992 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2016-09-17 17:50:40 8992 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete"

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I checked the MySQL error log but its just printing the [Note] MySQL normally shutdown.